# Converting multi row to a single row in new column is PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

I have this table :

```
|Role|  Att1 |
---------------
|R1  |  A    | 
|R1  |  B    |
|R2  |  C    |
|R2  |  D    |
```

And I want to consolidate the table into single row with multiple attributes like the table below

```
| Role  | Att1  | Att2
------------------------
| R1    |   A   |    B
| R2    |   C   |    D
```

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the tables as text, not as images.

Comment: [Crosstab questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+and+%28%5Bpivot%5D+or+%5Bcrosstab%5D%29)

Comment: Please check how to ask questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask